# When to use the feminine form when referring to a person?

Tags: grammaticality, feminine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tendency of using pronouns 'she/her' when talking about a random person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/876/tendency-of-using-pronouns-she-her-when-talking-about-a-random-person)

I was never interested in grammar and English in school.  Now that I am older, I am finding it was more important than I gave it credit.  Especially with the people I deal with at work.

Plus, I am finding an interest for it now.

Anyway, I've noticed over the years that when referring to a person, most books and articles tend to use the feminine form.

For example:

"A good programmer knows she should write tests."

Instead of using "he/she" they prefer to use "she".  Same is true for "her" instead of "his/her".

Where did this come from?  I'm not complaining, I actually prefer it.  Reminds me of a "ladies first" mentality.  But am I correct in assuming it is grammatically (or maybe politically) correct to use this form?

Thanks

Comment: That's interesting, as in my experience, the opposite is true.  The only time I've seen *she* used is when the antecedent is (or is likely) to be female..

Comment: Maybe feminists are more likely to complain if they are never mentioned than men in general ,)